# Random slideshow with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fade

I am doing a website, in the header of that website I want a "slideshow" that shows RANDOM images - this I already have with javascript.

I want to have the images to FADE in/out in instead of just changing them.

Other than that, I really want to know if there is any way I can make the script load pictures from a directory itself instead of I have to manually update the script each time I upload a picture.

Can this even be done with javascript, php, css or jquery?
Any alternatives? div change background random with fade? anything?

Here is the code I am using now.. its changing pictures with no problem.

```
<script language="javascript">

var delay=1000 //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex=0

var randomimages=new Array()

randomimages[0]="1.jpg"
randomimages[1]="5.jpg"
randomimages[2]="2.jpg"
randomimages[3]="4.jpg"
randomimages[4]="3.jpg"
randomimages[5]="6.jpg"

var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
{
preload[n]=new Image()
preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}

document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')

function rotateimage()
{

if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
}
else
curindex=tempindex

document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
}

setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)

</script>
```

Comment: Who's Mat? Did you mean to email this?

Comment: Mat was some admin i think, because he edit in my question, appearantly i wrote something wrong and he corrected me and put in a message in my question lol ...

Comment: Close-Voting for unclear-what-you-are-asking: A valid answer would be: "Yes. It is possible."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all of this can be done with javascript (almost), javascript itself can't scan folder contents for that you need some kind of server language, most likely you would use PHP to scan folder contents and return them to the client.

So basically you would need one of jquery ajax function, i would highly recommend [**post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

So now with ajax you can get all of your needed data about the folder.

Now about fade effect, you would need to use something like [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) or [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

As for randomness i'm pretty sure you can figure that out, just get a full list of images put them into array and use javascript [**random**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function to take random image from that array.

Comment: i did the random thing, and for scanned folders i just chose to manually put in the images i want in the slide .. but once again thank you for your help ... you guys are awesome

Comment: No problem, you can always reach me via email if you need more help, shinigamiworks@gmail.com

Comment: im glad there is guys like you :) i just added you to my gmail contacts, i am boutzamat ... i actually do have 1 more question (: